# Firebase data on update with key why inserting a new object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

In the image the red highlighted red box displayed key - generated by firebase

What I was trying to do is add menu items in the restaurant by restaurant key and same item to the globalMenu.

So, that the added menu items will be in globalMenu along with a copy in  `restaurant`.

What firebase does is adding a new entity in the database by duplicating the restaurant key instead adding just itemName into `restaurant`.

How can I resolve modelling database.

Here is my code:

```
//1. Add menu items to the globalMenu and to restaurant, and the restaurantId of the restaurant adding menu.
this.writeNewMenuItem = function(itemName, restaurantId) {
    // A post entry.
    var menuItem = {
        itemName: [itemName]
    };

    // Get a key for a new Post.
    var newItemKey = firebase.database().ref().child('globalMenu').push().key;

    // Write the new item's data simultaneously in the globalMenu list and the restaurants's menu list.
    var updates = {}, updatesRestaurant = {};
    updates['/globalMenu/' + newItemKey] = menuItem;
    updatesRestaurant['/restaurants/' + restaurantId + '/' + newItemKey] = menuItem;

    firebase.database().ref().update(updatesRestaurant);
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
//End
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//1. Add menu items to the globalMenu and to restaurant, and the restaurantId of the restaurant adding menu.
this.writeNewMenuItem = function(itemName, restaurantId) {
    // A post entry.
    var menuItem = {
        itemName: [itemName]
    };

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();

    // Get a key for a new Post.
    var newItem = ref
      .child('globalMenu')
      .push(menuItem);

    ref
      .child('restaurants')
      .child(restaurantId)
      .child(newItem.key)
      .update(menuItem);

}
```

Comment: .child(restaurantId) is still not working, when I did this..

ref
      .child('restaurants')
      .child(restaurantId)
      .child(newItem.key)
      .update(menuItem);

it inserted data by duplicating  restaurantId!!  This should insert under the restaurant.

Comment: Can you post an image with how you'd like the data to be stored ? It's hard to know from your description of the problem

Comment: Here is the image, hope you understand the problem!

http://i.stack.imgur.com/ugIjb.png

Comment: Have a look at the image you sent me. The keys are actually different. One is missing the leading -

Comment: Yes, that was a problem! Thanks for your help. It worked :)

Comment: Could you please help ..?
Now, I want to add list of items inside the itemName, like we do push and pop items from array!

Comment: Might be worth create a new question here. Because the original problem was resolved. Because it's getting complicated. I'm on mobile